# Unity WorldToScreenPoint returning huge values

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been trying to make an object follow the cursor, but `cam.WorldToScreenPoint` is returning huge values. Any idea why?

```
    Camera cam;

void Start()
{
    cam = Camera.main;
}


void Update()
{
    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    Debug.Log("mouse pos: " + mousePos);

    mousePos.z = -1;
    Debug.Log("mouse pos z update: " + mousePos);

    Vector3 unityMousePos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Debug.Log("unityMousePos: " + unityMousePos);

    transform.position = unityMousePos;
```

My screen is in 4:3 aspect ratio too. Not sure if that affects anything, but it might.
Here are some of the values it is returning:
mouse pos: (5.0, 5.0, 0.0)

mouse pos z update: (5.0, 5.0, -1.0)

unityMousePos: (331.8, 216.3, 10.0)

Comment: You are passing a screen point to WorldToScreenPoint, you can't do that. You can pass a world point to WorldToScreenPoint or a screen point to ScreenToWorldPoint but that's it, you can't mix those.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong method, WorldToScreenPoint returns the excat opposite of what you want, what you need is ScreenToWorldPoint

```
Camera cam;

void Start()
{
    cam = Camera.main;
}


void Update()
{
    Vector3 mousePosOnScreen = Input.mousePosition;

    mousePosOnScreen.z = -1;

    Vector3 worldPositionPointedByCursor = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(mousePosOnScreen);

    transform.position = worldPositionPointedByCursor;
}
```

Also you reused Input.mousposition in the callback, making the mousePosOnScreen.z = -1; you did useless (as it is not used)